# React Native Android Keyboard get instantly dismissed

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

this code shows a list where each row has a `TextInput` and is about 100 pixels high. When the keyboard pop ups it should make the list smaller by the height of the keyboard. This works if I select the upper rows. But if I select the bottom row it will show the keyboard and instantly hide it again. How can I keep the keyboard visible?
I tried the KeyboardAvoidingView from React Native but it makes everything worse. 
I tried to Animate the height change but than it behaves like a drunk ape. 
Changing the style from 'marginBottom' to 'height' has no effect.

```
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

class MyList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            keyboardHeight: 0,
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]),
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', e => this._keyboardDidShow(e));
        this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', e => this._keyboardDidHide(e));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
        this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
    }

    _keyboardDidShow (e) {
        this.setState({
            keyboardHeight: e.endCoordinates.height
        })

    }

    _keyboardDidHide () {
        this.setState({
            keyboardHeight: 0
        })
    }

    render() {
        const wrapper = {
            paddingTop: 30,
            marginBottom: this.state.keyboardHeight,
        };
        return (
            <View
                style={wrapper}
            >
                <ListView
                    enableEmptySections={true}
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={(rowData) => <MyRow data={rowData}/>}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this library can help you achieve the behavior you're looking for https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

Comment: Thanks but I've tried it already without success